# restore deleted git branch you don't know the name of

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, restore

So a colleague has asked me (as team trainee GitHub manager) if it's possible to recover a branch he created months ago, and recently deleted but can't remember the name of. Our working tree is as follows:

1. master branch (Main production version)
2. Staging branch (Testing
   before release to master)
3. Development branch (Main development branch where all future branches are created from
4. Personal branches (our induvidual branches that we make changes on, created from Development and then merged back into Development when complete)

The branch in question was created from Development, but it was never merged back in as it got old and work priorities pushed it back. Now there's time to work on it again we were wondering if it's possible to retrieve some kind of history that we can use to help us remember the branch name so we can then recover it...if at all possible...

Any advice would be appreciated! Have googled but most answers are based on branches that have been merged back in.

Comment: Was the lost branch ever pushed to remote? If it was, chances are that other team members have fetched it, and have not bothered to run remote prune on their local repo. Ask around if somebody still got an origin/the-lost-branch.

Comment: it would have been pushed, but most prune remote often, the other doesnt have any branches unless he's committed into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to check where the HEAD was point.

There may has the information like `checkout: moving from develop to personal_branch`, and the commit was the personal_branch where HEAD point to.

If the log history is cleaned in `.git/logs` unfortunately, you can use `git fsck --full` instead.

Comment: Also consider checking for dangling objects if reflog doesn't offer much help.

Comment: Thanks, how do you check for dangling objects? reflog didnt go back far enough.

Comment: Keep in mind that reflogs are not shared with origin / among clones, so the reflog can only be used on a clone that had visited the branch in question.  That said, unfortunately git appears to discard the branch-specific reflog as soon as the branch is deleted, so you'd be depending on the HEAD reflog it seems

Comment: Thanks, we were in luck as another colleague had the remote of it still, so we were able to trace through SHA and create a new branch. Everyone's answers were a great help thankyou!! :)

Comment: @Edmundo thanks for your reminder, I updated my answer :)

Comment: @Marina-MSFT anytime!

Answer (score 1):

Per Marina - MSFT's answer, best case would be to find help in the reflog of the repo that originally created the branch (since it has the best chance of having relevant reflog entries).

But if that doesn't help, plan B would be to locate the dangling commits.  Again this has the best chance of success in the repo that once housed the branch assuming it was deleted recently.  (Once the commits became unreachable, it becomes possible that `gc` will remove the commits entirely, and then the jig is up.)  One way to look for them would be

```
git fsck --unreachable --verbose
```

and check the output for something like

```
unreachable commit c0d3abcd...
```

You'll probably see several if you see any; you can use

```
git cat-file -p c0d3abcd
```

to see what each one is.  If you find one that represents the state you want to work from, put a branch on it.  (The original branch name will basically be unrecoverable at this point.)

If the local repo has lost the objects to a `gc`, you could try the remote.  It probably won't send the unreachable objects on a clone or pull request (though it's *possible* that it will depending on server implementation, you can't count on it), but it may provide API's for checking its reflogs or unreachable objects.